# Orion Context Broker - Nearest to point query

Tags: fiware-orion

We are working on a project involving Orion GE.

In this context, we would greatly benefit from a way to find the item that is nearest to given coordinates. Currently, you can query by items contained in a shape, but I was unable to find a "nearest to point" query. Is this possible?

(There are some workarounds such as searching by expanding radius, but this would not work in sparsely populated areas.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: current Orion version (0.27.0) doesn't allows to sort by "nearest to point" criteria, although a code hack is available providing such functionality.

However, sorting result is a planned functionality for NGSIv2 (see [this issue at github repository](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/1103)). Appart from sorting by attributes, nearest to point has been also taken into account. I'd recommend you to subscribe to notifications in that issue at github repository in order to be aware about when it gets implemented.

Moreover, a "hack" is currentlty avaiable (see the [corresponding pull request](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/pull/1651)) implementing nearest to point sorting. Thus, you could apply it to the current Orion code at develop branch, build it (the procedure is detailed [here](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/admin/build_source/index.html)) and get that functionality.

**EDIT:** since Orion 0.28.0 you can use the `orderBy=geo:proximity` URL parameter to order nearest to point query (see "Ordering results" section in the [NGSIv2 specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/)).

Comment: Answer has been updated with information regarding Orion 0.28.0 (to be released soon).